# Selenium can't find locate download link element by ID in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, download

I'm trying to get Selenium to automate uploading and downloading files from https://8mb.video/ I can upload the file just fine, but after it processes on the site Selenium can't locate the element for the download link even though the ID given matches the ID in the html. Here's my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Edge()

driver.get('https://8mb.video/')

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://8mb.video/")
s = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
s.send_keys("C:\\Users\\ijwto\\Desktop\\VUT\\bladee.mp4")

s = driver.find_element(By.ID, "rockandroll")
s.click()

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "dllink"))
    )
finally:
    print("nope")
```

I've also tried using element_to_be_clickable which didn't work, and checked for iframes in the HTML and didn't find any.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to download the file need to `click` on the `element` in the try block

Also if the intention of printing `Nope` in the finally block is to indicate if the element was not found then it can be added under `except` instead of `finally`

Note:- The wait time for WebDriverWait may increase in case the video you are trying to upload is large and the site requires more time to process it

Your solution would like

```
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get('https://8mb.video/')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://8mb.video/")
s = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
s.send_keys("C:\\Users\\ijwto\\Desktop\\VUT\\bladee.mp4")
s = driver.find_element(By.ID, "rockandroll")
s.click()
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "dllink"))
    )
    element.click()
except:
  print("Nope")
```